# How to paginate relations in a find/findOne using TypeORM

Tags: orm, nestjs, find, typeorm, one-to-many

Using TypeORM let's assume I have two entities in a one-to-many relationship. Product and ProductImages. Each product has many images.

When I do a findOne of a product I bring together multiple images related to this product. But when I do a find I would like to bring only one image because it will be the only image displayed in the product list.

How could I limit the number of images brought along with the product in a find query?

```
@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class ProductEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  model: string;

  @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 10, scale: 2, nullable: false })
  price: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: 0 })
  quantityInStock: number;

  @OneToMany(() => ProductImageEntity, (image) => image.product, {
    // cascade: ['insert', 'remove', 'soft-remove', 'update', 'recover'],
  })
  images: ProductImageEntity[];
}

@Entity({ name: 'products_images' })
export class ProductImageEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'int',
    nullable: false,
  })
  productId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => ProductEntity, (product) => product.images, {
    nullable: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'productId' })
  product: ProductEntity;
}



const product = await this.productRepo.find({
  where: { id: productId },
    relations: {
    images: true,
  },
});
```